# SSRS Cell Colour Dependent on Another Cell Value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

I'm trying change a cell background colour depending on another cell value, or if the cell value has zero I want a dash like this "-".

This is the formula I'm using, and currently the cell I want to have the dash in when the other cell is at Zero is showing 0.00

```
=IIF(Fields!RateAmount.Value = 0,"-",(switch(Fields!PercentageDifference.Value <= -10, "Red",
Fields!PercentageDifference.Value >= 10, "Red", True, "Green")))
```

When searching on here all I can find is an answer for googlesheets, if you do know of a post, please fele free to let me know!

Any help would be very well received! Cheers all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can change the background color in the same expression you're putting the dash "-".

I would try to change your expression with `=IIF(Fields!RateAmount.Value = 0,"-","(other text when it's not a dash)")`

Then, in properties of your cell, go to BackgroundColor and put something like `=switch(Fields!PercentageDifference.Value <= -10, "Red",
        Fields!PercentageDifference.Value >= 10, "Red", 
        True, "Green")`

Comment: THANK YOU @NickNick ! That's worked a treat.  I am using the column to work out the percentage difference of two numbers, so have just inserted the amount it would be if there are two numbers to work out, not Nulls or blanks etc and this has worked perfectly. Thanks again