# SSRS 2013 - Changing colour of cell dependent of outcome of expression within cell

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I've asked a similar question recently (See below) however I'm now struggling with a similar scenario. 
I have a cell with an expression which is a formula to calculate a % difference, and then depending on the value the percentage difference, I want the cell to change colour. if it's over 1% red, if it's under 1%, green.

The current expression which works to calculate the percentage is;

```
=(Sum(Fields!P1RateAmount.Value) - Sum(Fields!P1Amount.Value)) / (SUM(Fields!P1Amount.Value)) * 100
```

I'm presuming I need to wrap a IIF around it, but when I have tried it hasn't worked

If anyone could help me with this I'd be very grateful

Also for context, the formula can't be done in SQL to get a number as I'm using collapsing columns and the percentage formula I'm using in SQL brings back the first row when used within SSRS, and doesn't take into account the full sum

[Previous Question asked as referred to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757766/ssrs-cell-colour-dependent-on-another-cell-value/52759029#52759029)

Answer (score 1):

The expression for the **BackgroundColor** property of your text box would be:

```
=IIF( (Sum(Fields!P1RateAmount.Value) - Sum(Fields!P1Amount.Value)) / SUM(Fields!P1Amount.Value) * 100 > 1, "#fff5fa", "MintCream")
```

[image: Property view]

I prefer a light shade of green or red but you can substitute the colors with **Red** and **Green** if you want to hit them over the head with it.

Comment: Apologies, just tried it, and it's stayed the same again

Comment: So this has half worked. Everything currently is in green, I haven cells with the number -13.11 and 5.75, they should be in red, and 0.10 should be in green, which it currently is.  any help on this at all?

Comment: I have got it working but with 'me.Value' so for example =Switch(
me.value <=-1 OR me.value >=1, "Red"
,me.value >-1 OR me.value <1, "Green"
)

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who may be looking at something similar, the following worked for me

```
=Switch(
me.value <=-1 OR me.value >=1, "Red"
,me.value >-1 OR me.value <1, "Green"
)
```

I think this is because the cell already had an expression of

```
=(Sum(Fields!P1RateAmount.Value) - Sum(Fields!P1Amount.Value)) / (SUM(Fields!P1Amount.Value)) * 100
```

to get number, the 'IIF' and then referencing the cells wouldn't work. However me.value would look at the value of the cell rather than working the formula, thus bringing back the desired colour